# Conditionally select DataFrame rows based on duplicate categorical values in different columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame`, and I would like to keep only the rows that have identical values in the two first columns within the same row.

```
County_in = pd.Series(["001","001","002"], dtype="category")
County_out = pd.Series(["001","003","001"], dtype="category")
Value = pd.Series([2,4,6], dtype="int")

foo = pd.DataFrame({'County_in' : County_in,
                    'County_out' : County_out,
                    'Value' : Value})

foo

   County_in  County_out    value
0  001        001           2
1  001        003           4
2  002        001           6
```

I would like to have this result:

```
   County_in  County_out    value
1  001        003           4
2  002        001           6
```

I have tried:

```
 foo_2 = foo[~foo.County_out.isin(foo.County_in)]
```

But it removes the rows even if the value is not identical within the same row:

```
foo

   County_in  County_out    value
1  001        003           4
```

Is there a function I could use?

Comment: Are you just wanting row by row comparison? If so, the reason your attempt failed is that `isin` tests for membership of the entire series against all values so you get multiple positive rows returned

Comment: Yes, for the entire DataFrame.

Comment: What does your last comment mean?

Comment: It means that I indeed want a row by row comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you just want this:

```
In [80]:
foo[foo['County_in'] != foo['County_out']]

Out[80]:
  County_in County_out  value
1       001        003      4
2       002        001      6
```

**EDIT**

You can't compare categoricals when the categories are different, however, if you cast the values to `str` then it works:

```
In [99]:
foo[foo['County_in'] != foo['County_out'].astype(str)]

Out[99]:
  County_in County_out  Value
1       001        003      4
2       002        001      6
```

See the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#comparisons

Comment: Thanks !
I also tried this, but I have this error message with the DataFrame I am working on :
    TypeError: Categoricals can only be compared if 'categories' are the same

Comment: Jesus if your dtypes are categoricals it would help if your sample data **actually** represented your dataset don't you think? Please post representative data and code

Comment: Thanks a lot, EdChum!